# Why am I getting a conversion error here?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, adapter

Both the adapter class and the target class implement the same interface...why can I not treat them like the same object?

```
interface ISmartPhone
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }

    void ShowTextWithImage();
}

    public class BasicFlipPhoneAdapter : ISmartPhone
{
    IBasicPhone basicPhone;
    public BasicFlipPhoneAdapter(IBasicPhone basicPhone)
    {
        this.basicPhone = basicPhone;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public void ShowTextWithImage()
    {
        basicPhone.ShowBasicText();
    }
}

public class iPhone : ISmartPhone
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public void ShowTextWithImage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("O.o cool image!");
    }
}
```

Error occurs:

```
iPhone flipPhoneAdapter = new BasicFlipPhoneAdapter(flipPhone);
```

Comment: What does the interface look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because they're *not* the same object type. A `BasicFlipPhoneAdapter` is *not* an `iPhone`. What you *should* be able to do is:

```
ISmartPhone flipPhoneAdapter = new BasicFlipPhoneAdapter(flipPhone);
```

Note the type of the `flipPhoneAdapter` variable - it's `ISmartPhone`, not `iPhone`.

Comment: This is correct, silly mistake on my part.  Thanks for the quick reply and resolution.

Answer (score 1):

try `ISmartPhone flipPhoneAdapter = new BasicFlipPhoneAdapter(flipPhone);`

Answer (score 1):

They are not same **objects**. But they can be shaped in your **ISmartPhone interface**. You can cast both of your `BasicFlipPhoneAdapter` and `iPhone` instance to `ISmartPhone` and use the exposed signature.

Answer (score 1):

Since both are derived from `ISmartPhone`, you can certainly treat either a `BasicFlipPhoneAdapter` and an `iPhone` as an `ISmartPhone`, e.g.,

```
ISmartPhone flipPhoneAdapter = new BasicFlipPhoneAdapter(flipPhone);
```

However, you cannot implicitly treat an `iPhone` as an `BasicFlipPhoneAdapter`. They have the same base type, but can differ besides that.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
ISmartPhone flipPhoneAdapter = new BasicFlipPhoneAdapter(flipPhone);
```

iPhone is not a super type of BasicFlipPhoneAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Just because two classes implement the same interface doesn't mean they're interchangeable.

```
iPhone flipPhoneAdapter = new BasicFlipPhoneAdapter(flipPhone);
```

is invalid because you're trying to assign a variable of type `iPhone` an instance of class `BasicFlipPhoneAdapter`. On the other hand, you can have methods which operate on any class which implements the interface. Take this function prototype:

```
public void DoSomethingPhoneLike(ISmartPhone phone) {
    // ... do things with phone, like phone.ShowTextWithImage()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need more detail on what ISmartPhone extends to answer for sure but it looks like you are trying to say that all items that could be "flipPhone" are iPhone. Based on just the code you provided I'm assuming all "flipPhone" instances would be an ISmartPhone so if you change

```
iPhone flipPhoneAdapter = new BasicFlipPhoneAdapter(flipPhone);
```

to

```
ISmartPhone flipPhoneAdapter = new BasicFlipPhoneAdapter(flipPhone);
```

it should work. Or if ISmartPhone does extend IBasicPhone then change the type of flipPhoneAdapeter to IBasicPhone.